# 2000 Dodge ram wont idle!

Tags: dodge, idle, ram

I am working on a 2000 Dodge Ram 1500 4x4 with the 5.2 auto in it.. I have tried everything i can possibly think to fix it. It always starts, and drives down the road, but will not idle unless i pull a vaccume line off the plenum.. doesn't matter what line, booster, pcv, or whatever.. Is there anything else it could possible be? here is a list of everything that i have changed.

Plugs Wires dist cap rotor button dist module iac tps map sensor crank sensor 02's plenum/intake gaskets battery alternator

basically everything short of the ecu/computer..... Any help is appreciated???? really baffeled!

Comment: Just to be sure - You cleaned the throttle body, idle valve port, and replaced/tested the idle valve?

Comment: Did you preform a memory reset with a scantool after you replaced the parts? you can't just disconnect the battery on Chryslers. You need to do a relearn.

Comment: Along the lines of what @Ben is saying, I was wondering if the throttle position sensor might need recalibrated. Removing a vacuum line will just increase the idle speed a little bit, which would allow it to idle easier (though it's not optimal, obviously). By doing this, you're introducing unmetered air into the intake, which will screw with your fuel trims.

Comment: Disconnect the MAP sensor electrical connector with engine off (front of thottle body), start it, if it idles now, replace the MAP sensor

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the MAP sensor electrical connector with engine off (front of thottle body), start it, if it idles now, replace the MAP sensor.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this one has a MAF, I'd have to double check but most Chrysler v8's don't.

Comment: It appears @Ben is correct. I don't see one listed for it, either.